# button should appear 30 seconds from the end

Tags: javascript

```
<input style="display: none;" type="submit" id="btn3d" value="Proceed" class="btn btn-primary btn3d">

    </form>


<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#btn3d').delay(10000).show(0);   
</script>
```

how can i make the button display 30 seconds to the end of the video without hard coding it because length of videos i plan on uploading are not the same length.

Comment: Do you know how to get the duration of the video ?

Comment: What video player do you use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ended` event of the video.

I don't know the structure of you HTML but you can do something like this:

```
<video id="myVideo">
   ...
</video>

<input id="btn3d" ...>

<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on("timeupdate","#myVideo",function() {

        const videoElem = $('#myVideo')[0];

        if(videoElem.duration - videoElem.currentTime <= 30) {
            $('#btn3d').show();
        }else{
            $('#btn3d').hide();
        }

    });

  })
</script>
```

Comment: This would show the button 30s *after* the end of the video.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You're right. I updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Running time / length of a video can be obtained by the '**duration**' attribute of '**Video**' element.

**Here is an example of how a button can be shown 30 seconds before the video ends:**

```
    var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo")

    // Find video duration when user clicks 'play'
    myVideo.onplay = function() {

        var duration = myVideo.duration
        var elapsedTime = myVideo.currentTime

        // Waiting time = (duration - elapsedTime - 30) seconds
        var waitingTime = (duration - elapsedTime - 30)*1000


        if (waitingTime <= 0) {
           // Minimum waiting time = 1 second
           waitingTime = 1000
        }

        // Show button after waiting time elapses
        setTimeout(
             function(){ 
                // Code to show button 
             }, 
             waitingTime
        )    
    }
```

**More information:**

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_play.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_duration.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_currenttime.asp

Comment: If the user pauses the video, then the callback will fire once more for each such pause. Not too much of a problem when it's just showing a button, but could be an issue if something more complicated were done.

Comment: Yes. Good observation, Niet.  The currentTime attribute must be used to calculate remaining time. I just updated the code sample to deduct elapsed time from totla duration, using the currentTime attribute.